# How to open ports if there are multiple sub network behind a router or Public ip

Tags: private, ips

Currently this is the our office network. We currently have a single Public ip from the ISP and we have created a single Private ip network behind the NAT as shown below :

public ip ( WAN )  - 122.x.x.1, 
gateway ip ( LAN ) - 10.0.0.1

client machines or servers ips range from - 10.0.0.2 to 10.0.0.254
subnetmask  - 255.255.255.0

Gateway is the Cisco Router RV042. In order to open ports like 80 or 443 so that our websites can be accessible publically we used to do some Port forwarding in Router ( eg: 10.0.0.25 + 80 ) like that.

Our requirement is to create more subnets behind the NAT or Router like for instance 10.0.1.0, 10.0.2.0 etc per client and to how to map to these networks if we have multiple Public ips from the ISP.

for eg : a webserver running on a subnet with 10.0.0.30 needs to open the port 80 and another mail server running on private network say 10.0.2.15 needs to open 25 port. Basically how to map different subnet private ips to Public ips I don't have much  touch with networking concepts so please help me to accomplish my task.

Answer (score 1):

The RV042 only supports port-based vlans.  You'd need something like the RV180 to do actual subnetting.  OR you could get a small layer 3 switch to accomplish this and have a small /30 subnet between it and the RV042.  Either way works.

As far as how to subnet and map the different private IPs to Public IPs, you would do no different than you are doing today (assumption).  You'd setup the NAT rules and ACLs as needed on the router/firewall.  You'd need to make sure the router knows where these subnets exist (which it would if the routes were local like a RV180, or you'd define them with their next hop being the layer 3 switch if you buy just a l3 switch).

Best I can say is that this isn't complex, but if you've never done it before I'd simply suggest starting to set it up based on the manuals and then if you get stuck as another question here with details on the configs, topology you want, etc.

Comment: Hi TheCleaner .. thanks for the valuable information. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need a router that supports VLANs to accomplish this task. Each separate IP subnet would have its own VLAN, and the router would route traffic between these VLANs and outside world.

However, looking at the specifications of Cisco RV042, it doesn't support VLANs. Therefore you cannot do what you want with your hardware.

You need to replace RV042 with another router that supports VLANs.

Comment: Hi Tero, Thanks for the quick reply. Could you suggest me any Router model that supports VLANS. We have about 20 clients now and we are planning a network structure in such a way that there will be a subnet / client. So do we need to buy 20 VLAN supported Routers? Can you guide me how to map Public ips wrt internal private ips of these subnets.